# Word for "to wrong by treating the same?"

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, nouns

I was wondering if there is a word for treating a group the same as another, even though they have different needs. It would be a bit like an antonym of discrimination, but most antonyms of discrimination are positive (fairness, impartiality, etc.) Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please use supply a sentence or three where this word (or phrase?) that you’re looking for would comfortably fit?

Comment: It's not uncommon to see ***one size fits all*** used disparagingly (in contexts where such provision is clearly *not* appropriate, such as army issue shoes).

Answer (score 1):

How about "This undifferentiated approach to providing health care would result in worse outcomes for both groups".

Answer (score 0):

Without a few actual example sentences in which such a term or expression might be used, it is not really possible to provide an answer that will work where you want to use it, since we don’t know where that might be.

If something along these lines were the intended use:

> Outsiders regularly <sup>**(*verb or verb phrase*)**</sup> members of 
>   the smaller Hopi tribe with those of the larger and historically distinct
>   Navajo tribe.  This <sup>**(*noun or noun phrase*)**</sup> of
>   two such disparate peoples is likely to earn the displeasure of both, and the outright hostility of the smaller and less well-known group.

Then these pairs could be made to reasonably fit those insertion points, adjusting as necessary:

- to confuse, this confusion
- to conflate, this conflation
- to mistake, this mistaking
- to misidentify, this misidentification
- to mix up, this mix-up
- to lump together, this lumping together
- to fail to distinguish (between), this failure to distinguish (between)

However, different prototype sentences could lead to choices entirely different from these.  For example:

> **Stereotyping** all members of both group X and group Y to be or act one way or another is an **over-generalization** with roots ranging from simple ignorance to overt malice.

There are plenty of groups that could be swapped in there:

- Americans and Canadians
- Ozzies and Kiwis
- Ozzies and Harriets
- Danes and Norwegians
- Inuits and Yukits
- Englishmen and Scots
- Englishmen and Europeans
- Japanese and Koreans
- Chinese and Japanese
- Chinese and Tibetans
- Catholics and Protestants
- Catalans and Castilians
- Italians and Spaniards
- Spaniards and Portuguese
- Portuguese and Brazilians
- Jews and Arabs
- Jews and Christians
- hawks and falcons
- swallows and swifts
- storks and cranes
- wolves and foxes
- dogs and hyenas
- black bears and grizzly bears
- panda bears and Teddy bears
- grizzly bears and gummy bears
- butterflies and moths
- plants and fungi
- oaks and maples
- lettuce and cabbage
- broccoli and cauliflower
- stars and planets

Comment: Woe betide whoever mixes up a grizzly bear and a gummy bear. Surprised you didn’t include _apples and oranges_, though, seeing as it’s probably the most common one. ;-)

Comment: @Janus That's because to me, apples and oranges are in the same category: spherical reddish sweet juice-making tree-fruit of virtually the same size. For actual category errors, I prefer miscomparing apples and avarice or oranges and orneriness.

Answer (score 0):

The phrasal verb ***lump sb/sth together*** conveys the idea and it has a negative sense.

> to put different groups together and think about them or deal with them in the same way:
>
> *All the children are lumped together in one class, regardless of their ability.*
>
> [[Cambridge Dictionaries]](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/lump-sb-sth-together)

Answer (score 0):

One verb that I have frequently heard used in recent years to indicate a failure to distinguish properly between two similar-looking but different things is *conflate*.

Merriam-Webster Online gives three definitions of *conflate*:

> **conflate** *transitive verb* (1610) **1 a :**  to bring together : fuse **b :** confuse **2 :**  to combine (as two readings of a text) into a composite whole

The relevant definition is 1b: "confuse," where the confusion is between different entities or categories that results in their being treated as one. As Merriam-Webster goes on to point out, antonyms of *conflate* include *difference*, *differentiate*, *discriminate*, *distinguish*, and *separate*.

Comment: However, "conflate" has, of late, come to mean "confuse" as in mistaking one for the other.  This does not appear to be the meaning the OP was seeking.